# If $(a,b)=1$, then $ \gcd(a^2+b^2,a^3+b^3)\mid (a-b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> If $(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a^2+b^2,a^3+b^3)\mid (a-b)$

The only way that can help is to find some common factor of $a^2+b^2$ and $a^3+b^3$. 
That does not seem obvious enough, so will directly try to divide $a^3+b^3$ by $a^2+b^2$.
This leads to nowhere too.

It seems that need to use the fact that $a,b$ are relatively prime, but am unable to use that.

 Let for some suitable integers $x, y$, have $ax +by =1$.

Comment: Let $d$ a divisor of $a^2+b^2$ and of $a^3+b^3$. Then $d $ divide $a^3+b^3-a(a^2+b^2)=b^2(b-a)$, and of course $d$ divide also $a^2(b-a)$. Now $a^2$ and $b^2$ are relatively prime, use your last remark.

Comment: @Kelenner You have multiplied by an integer (here, $a$ to $(a^2+b^2)$) to achieve $b^2(b-a)$, and similarly $a^2(b-a)$. Next, as $(a,b)=1$, so used the property that $(a,b)=1 \implies (a^i,b^i)=1, i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Here, have taken $i=2$. Next, (i) $d\mid a^2(b-a)$, (ii) $d\mid b^2(b-a)$. However, am unable to find the next step based on the equality $ax+by=1$. It is not helping me out. -- Please help.

Comment: I hope that I have not read you correctly, or am not able to do so. It seems quite simple, as $d$ is $\gcd$ of $a^2+b^2$ and $a^3+b^3$. Now, as $d\mid a^2(b-a)$ and $d\mid b^2(b-a)$, with $(a^2, b^2)=1$, as $(a,b)=1$. So, $d$ cannot divide both $a^2$ & $b^2$ at the same time, but must divide $(b-a)$. Additionally, $d\nmid a$ or $d\nmid b$, or both $a,b$ are not divisible by $d$; but $d\mid (b-a)$.

Comment: The remark at the end of your post (with $a^2$ and $b^2$ coprime) say that there exist $x,y$ integers such that $xa^2+yb^2=1$. Now multiply by $b-a$, You get that $b-a=xa^2(b-a)+yb^2(b-a)$, hence $d$ divide $b-a$.

Comment: @Kelenner Yes, as $d$ will divide all linear combinations of $a^2(b-a), b^2(b-a)$. But, I also arrived by a new route. But, your way is far more glorious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say $$d=\gcd(a^2+b^2,a^3+b^3)$$ then $d\mid (a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$ and $d\mid a^2+b^2$ so, we get:
 $$d\mid ab(a+b) = (a+b)(a^2+b^2)-  (a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$$

Now suppose there is prime $p$ such that $p\mid d$ and $p\mid a$.  Then $p\mid a^2$ and so $p\mid b^2 = (a^2+b^2)-a^2$. A contradiction, since $a,b$ are relatively prime. So $a,d$ are relatively prime (and $b,d$ also) and $$d\mid a+b\Longrightarrow d\mid a(a+b)=a^2+ab$$

so $$ d\mid (a^2+ab)- (a^2+b^2)= b(a-b)$$
By Euclid lemma we have $d\mid a-b$.

Comment: Please help me with how got :$d\mid ab(a+b)$, am stuck.

Comment: Since $d\mid a^2+b^2$ we have  $d\mid ab(a^2+b^2)$. Also $d\mid (a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$. So $d$ divide their difference.

Comment: Still not clear about how $d\mid a^2 +b^2$ led to $d\mid ab(a^2+b^2)$. At max, it is a trick to achieve the desired subtraction, I mean you multiplied by any factor (just, must be an integer) to achieve the needed subtraction. I hope I am correct.

Comment: if $d\mid m$ then $d\mid km$ for all $k$

Comment: Too sorry for trying to edit a correct answer.

Comment: I hope the answer has typo: $d\mid ab(a+b) = (a+b)(a^2+b^2) - (a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$. I mean the multiplication factor for $(a^2+b^2)$ should be $(a+b)$, not $ab$. But, am not going to do the mistake of trying to edit again, as some confusion occurred then. It is your answer, I am nobody.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\left(a^3+b^3\right)-b\left(a^2+b^2\right)=(a-b)a^2
$$
and
$$
a\left(a^2+b^2\right)-\left(a^3+b^3\right)=(a-b)b^2
$$
and if
$$
ax+by=1
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=(ax+by)^3\\
&=a^2\left(ax^3+3x^2by\right)+b^2\left(3axy^2+by^3\right)
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
a-b
&=(a-b)\left(\color{#C00}{a^2}\left(ax^3+3x^2by\right)+\color{#090}{b^2}\left(3axy^2+by^3\right)\right)\\
&=\color{#C00}{\left(\left(a^3+b^3\right)-b\left(a^2+b^2\right)\right)}\left(ax^3+3x^2by\right)\\
&+\color{#090}{\left(a\left(a^2+b^2\right)-\left(a^3+b^3\right)\right)}\left(3axy^2+by^3\right)\\
&=\boldsymbol{\left(a^3+b^3\right)}\left(ax^3+3x^2by-3axy^2-by^3\right)\\
&+\boldsymbol{\left(a^2+b^2\right)}\left(3a^2xy^2+aby^3-abx^3-3x^2b^2y\right)
\end{align}
$$
which means that
$$
\left.\left(a^2+b^2,a^3+b^3\right)\,\middle|\,a-b\right.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for a new way to solve such problems.